How to handle push notifications in Flutter when the app is closed using SignalR in Flutter
I am researching how to implement notifications in Flutter, specifically how they can work when the app is closed or the screen is locked. I'm using SignalR on the backend, so I need a solution in Flutter that can push notifications even when the app is not open. For displaying notifications, I plan to use flutter_local_notifications, but I'm unsure how to handle push notifications when the app is closed. I wanted to use Firebase, but I need something that is free.

OneSignal has a free plan that include unlimited notifications. It's not a the best SDK in town for Flutter but it works.

Does firebase include unlimited free notifications?
